How to disable matBadge animations in Angular Material?
By clicking on the icon, I want only the number inside the matBadge to change. I don't want an animation to be made when clicking. How do I do that?
<div class="action_like">
        <mat-icon
          matBadge="{{ post.likes.length }}"
          matBadgeColor="primary"
          [color]="post.likes.includes(currentUserId) ? 'accent' : 'primary'"
          (click)="toggleLike(post)"
        >
          {{
            post.likes && post.likes.includes(currentUserId)
              ? "favorite"
              : "favorite_border"
          }}
        </mat-icon>
      </div>

I tried this, but it didn't work:
.matBadge {
  transition: none !important;
}

.matBadgeContent {
  transition: none !important;
}


please share the minimal reproducible code stackblitz reference what animation are you taking about? please provide the steps to reproduce

Cannot reproduce. For me in a simple reproduction, no animation is made.
